# How to get only one result from foreach(PHP)

Tags: php

The code loop an array and display all views for a user. Now things changed and I just need to display one result from a foreach loop. How do I do that?

```
<table class="report_edits_table">
<thead>
  <tr class="dates_row">
  <?php foreach($report['edits'] as $report_edit) : ?>
    <td colspan="2" report_edit_id="<?php echo $report_edit['id'] ?>"><div class="date_container">
    <?php if($sf_user->hasCredential(Attribute::COACHING_EDIT_ACCESS)) : ?>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Remove</span>
    <?php endif?>
    <?php echo "View " . link_to($report_edit['created'], sprintf('coaching/viewReportEdit?reportedit=%s', $report_edit['id']), array('title' => 'View This Contact')) ?> </div></td>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($report['edits_titles'] as $index => $title) : ?>
  <tr class="coach_row">
    <?php for ($i=max(0, count($report['edits'])-2); $i<count($report['edits']); $i++) : $report_edit = $report['edits'][$i] ?>
    <td class="name_column"><?php echo $title ?></td>
    <td class="value_column"><?php echo $report_edit[$index] ?></td>
    <?php endfor ?>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, but you can always `break;` to jump out of the `foreach()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `break` command for simple conversion:

```
<?php for ... ?>
    ... stuff here ...
    <?php break; ?>
<?php endfor ... ?>
```

A better solution would be to remove the `foreach` completely.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to grab the first element from an array without having to loop through the rest of them.

PHP provides a set of functions for situations like this.

To get the first element in an array, start off using the [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function to position the array pointer to the start of the array, then use the [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function to read the element that the pointer is looking at.

So your code would look like this:

```
<?php
reset($report['edits']);
$report_edit = current($report['edits']);
?>
```

Now you can work with `$report_edits` without having to use a `foreach()` loop.

(note that the array pointer does actually start by default at the first record, so you *could* skip the `reset()` call, but it's best practice not to do that because it might have been changed elsewhere in your code without you realising it)

If you want to move on to the next record after that, you can use the `next()` function. As you can see, if you wanted to, it would theoretically be possible to use these functions to write an alternative type of `foreach()` loop. There wouldn't be any point in using them them that way, but it's possible. But they do allow more fine-grained control over the array, which is handy for situations like yours.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of ways

1. Access the index of the array element in question directly
2. Update whatever logic fetches/generates the array to only return the element of interest
3. Use a for loop that terminates after a single loop
4. array_filter your array to get the element of interest
5. Break at the end of your foreach loop so it terminates after the first iteration
6. Conditionally check your index in the foreach loop and only output markup if the index matches the element of interest
7. And so on

I'd recommend just getting the array element of interest (number 2 on the list) as it means less data bouncing around your code (and probably between your PHP box and the database if you're populating the array from an SQL server)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method?

Place a `break` as the last line of your foreach. It'll execute once, then quit. (As long as *which* element you stop on is of no importance).

Secondary method: use [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) or [`array_shift`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on your `$report['edits']` or `$report['edits_titles']` to get on element, lose the for loop, and reference the element you just retrieved.

For example:

```
//
// current
//
foreach ($report['edits'] as $report_edit) :
  /* markup */
endforeach;

//
// modified version
//
$report_edit = array_shift($report['edits']);
  /* markup */
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php break ?>` before `<?php endforeach ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
example :: 

<?php  
  foreach ($this->oFuelData AS $aFuelData ) {
    echo $aFuelData['vehicle'];
    break;                      
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it for reference

```
    foreach($array as $element) {
    if ($element === reset($array))
        echo $element;

    if ($element === end($array))
        echo $element;
    }
```