# Show only term text and link of custom post type category that is being viewed

Tags: wordpress, loops, get, categories

I am trying to show the category name in a wordpress loop for the category page of a custom taxonomy and I have done many searches for an answer and I have not been able to find it or I am doing something wrong. I am trying to show only 1 term. The categories have sub categories and another level of subcategories as well.

So I need the term to dynamically reflect the term of page that is being viewed. I have this code that works but it displays the whole list of terms associated with the post and since the post has parent, child, and granchild terms, I don't want it to show all the terms at once.

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'videoscategory');

echo '<h2>';

foreach ($terms as $term) {

echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'videoscategory').'">'.$term->name.'</a>';

}

echo '</h2>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the `foreach`, which is looping through every term. A quick and dirty way to do it is to insert `<?php break; ?>` before the `endfor`

See this thread for more: [How to get only one result from foreach(PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689626/how-to-get-only-one-result-from-foreachphp)